# Create a type of pair tensor from cartesian product of 1D array with itself

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of strings, like

```
arr = np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
```

I want to create a torch tensor matrix with the type of pairs that will be created by cartesian product. So, the result would be a 8x8 tensor where:

- if the `row == 'A'` and column is `col == 'B'`, then the value in a matrix is for example `1`;
- if the `row == 'B'` and column is `col == 'C'`, then the value in a matrix is for example `2`,
- `0` otherwise (i.e. if row is the same as col).

How can I achieve that?

So far, I have tried to do something as follows:

```
arr = np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
_, arr = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
arr = torch.tensor(arr)
arr += 1

out = torch.cartesian_prod(arr, arr).reshape(8, 8, 2)
out = out[:, :, 1] * out[:, :, 0]
torch.where(torch.sqrt(out) == torch.sqrt(out).int(), 0, out)

tensor([[0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [3, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

But it feels a bit clumsy (even the values are quite random and not 0, 1, 2...), so I wanted to hear other ideas.

Comment: Can you please provide or mention what you have tried so far? Or with some research what have you found?

Comment: I've provided my solution, but I actually wanted to hear probably better ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Combine meshgrid and fancy indexing

### Comments on the published solution

There are two flaws in the approach published in the original post.

First, the square root of the product of two *unequal* numbers can be an integer. For example, the root of `1 * 4` is two which is an integer number. Therefore, zeros will be inserted as identifiers of pairs like  `(1, 4), (2, 8), (3, 12), ...`, which was certainly not intended.

Next, equal identifiers will be set for some different pairs. For example, we have the identifier 6 for pairs `(1, 6)` and `(2, 3)` in this model. To differentiate them, it is necessary to change the way the pair is identified.

### New solution

Let's create a matrix of identifiers for all possible pairs based on `range(number_of_pairs).reshape(...)`:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
unique, codes = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)

n = len(unique)
pairs_id = np.arange(n*n).reshape(n, n)   # assign unique id's to each pair
pairs_id = np.triu(pairs_id, k=1)         # put 0 on the diagonal and below it
pairs_id = pairs_id + pairs_id.T          # mirror the upper triangular matrix

# p.s. A hidden trick that is better expressed explicitly: 
# we can start the range from 0, because in this model
# the very first element is inevitably removed by replacing with zero
```

Now we have unique identifiers for each pair of initial unique values with the exception that the identifier is independent of the ordering of the pair, and for those pairs in which both values are equal, the identifier is zero.

To get the desirable answer, we can use [numpy.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) instead of Cartesian product and [Integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```
left, right = np.meshgrid(codes, codes)
answer = pairs_id[left, right]
```

### Summary code and output

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
unique, codes = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)

n = len(unique)
pairs = np.arange(n*n).reshape(n, n)
pairs = np.triu(pairs, k=1)
pairs = pairs + pairs.T

left, right = np.meshgrid(codes, codes)
answer = pairs[left, right]

print(
    f'{unique = }',
    f'{codes = }',
    f'{pairs = }',
    f'{answer = }',
    sep='\n' + '\N{Horizontal Line Extension}'*30 + '\n'
)
```

Output:

```
unique = array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='<U1')
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
codes = array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
pairs = array([
       [0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 5],
       [2, 5, 0]])
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
answer = array([
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [2, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using simple broadcasting and binary encoding:

```
a = 2**np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)[1]
out = a[:,None] ^ a # easier than np.where(a[:,None]==a, 0, a[:,None]+a), thanks @Vitalizzare
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

If you want numbers from 0 to n, factorize again:

```
out2 = np.unique(out, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(out.shape)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Intermediates:

```
# a
array([1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4])

# a[:,None]==a
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True]])

# a[:,None]+a
array([[2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8]])
```

Comment: You don't need `numpy.where` in this case, `a[:,None] ^ a` (i.e. bitwise logical xor) is enough. But there's a limitation in the number of possible values you can encode this way - not more then 64, I guess. If we're talking not about a sequence of Latin letters but, e.g., a sequence of ASCII characters, or a sequence of tokens if this is a part of some NLP task, then your solution (which looks elegant) doesn't work.

Comment: @Vitalizzare yes, that's right XOR is easier. Regarding the limitation of the bit number you can probably use several numbers to encode more possibilities (e.g, first running `np.divmod(np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)[1], 64)` and encoding both parts). I'll have to think about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using broadcasting and string concatenation:

```py
# pairwise concatenation with broadcasting
pairs = np.char.add(arr[:, np.newaxis], arr[np.newaxis, :])

# replacing concatenation where elements are equal by an empty string
pairs[arr[:, np.newaxis] == arr[np.newaxis, :]] = ''

labels = (
    # get indices of unique array ( size=(len(arr)**2,) )
    np.unique(pairs, return_inverse=True)[1]
    # reshape to (len(arr), len(arr))
    .reshape(pairs.shape)
)

labels
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Finally, of course, `labels` can be used to create a `torch.array`.